# Buscar un string en un txt y comprobar si existe o no

Tags: script, batch

Estoy haciendo un pequeño script y me he atascado en esta parte.
Quiero comprobar si existe un nombre en el txt y en caso que exista realizar una tarea.
El problema esta en que no consigo diferenciar si existe o no el string dentro del txt.

La variable mivar la rellena el usuario al entrar (ya he comprobado que se guarde bien el valor en la variable)

```
SET file = comprobar.txt

findstr %mivar% %file% >nul
if %errorlevel% equ 1 (
    echo FALLO
) else (
    echo OK
)
```

Alguien sabe que puede estar fallando? gracias!

Comment: El nombre ¿contiene espacios?

Answer (score 0):

decidí hacer lo que tu quieres hacer, y la mejor forma que se me ocurrió fue con lo siguiente.

```
@ECHO OFF 

FINDSTR %1 %2 > nul
IF %errorlevel% EQU 0 ECHO Si existe la palabra %1
IF %errorlevel% EQU 1 ECHO No existe la palabra %1
```